# I need to split a list into a list of lists [Python]

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list of items in this format:

```
['2', '', '9', '24', '1', '7', '12', '4', '', '18', '13', '34', '3', '10']
```

I need to turn it into a list of lists separated by the empty items:

```
[['2'], ['9', '24', '1', '7', '12', '4'], ['18', '13', '34', '3', '10']]
```

I'm simply not sure how to go about this. I did try doing a nested loop but that's not working as planned.

I've discovered that there is a way to do it using itertools.groupby but I can't figure out the syntax for that.

I appreciate all help given! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = ['2', '', '9', '24', '1', '7', '12', '4', '', '18', '13', '34', '3', '10']
>>> [list(items) for status, items in groupby(a, lambda v: v != '') if status]
[['2'], ['9', '24', '1', '7', '12', '4'], ['18', '13', '34', '3', '10']]
```

`groupby` takes an iterable and a function and returns items grouped into sets depending on the return value of the function. This example checks if the return value is `True` and then explicitly outputs a list of lists (as that's what you wanted in your example).

*Edit*: Here's a slightly more readable version, suggested by @JonClements in the comments (uses string casting to `bool` instead of the `lambda` function):

```
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, bool) if k]
```

If you don't explicitly need a list, you could also do something like:

```
>>> for k, v in groupby(a, bool):
...     if k:
...         # do something with each group of values (v)
...
```

Comment: This is the way I'd do it, but I'd replace the `lambda v: v != ''` with `bool`

Comment: What did they do to my beloved **readable** Python language? Or, to put it in a way they'll understand: `[actions for actions in language.python.desecration()]` :-)

Comment: `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, bool) if k]` works nicely here

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. And I learned how to use this tool! Hopefully this shows up on Google for others with this issue.

Comment: +1 for a simple illustration of the use of lambda although @JonClements approach is equally valid

Comment: @bogeyc and using a builtin callable is more efficient than a lambda with a comparison, but yeah :)

Answer (score 3):

```
myList = ['2', '', '9', '24', '1', '7', '12', '4', '', '18', '13', '34', '3', '10']
newList = []
tmp = []
for item in myList:
    if item:
        tmp.append(item)
    else:
        newList.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
newList.append(tmp)          # may need to wrap this in an
                             #   "if tmp != []" thingy
```

Comment: You need a final `newList.append(tmp)` after the for loop to get the last sublist added. I had basically the same solution, with the same bug.

Comment: what abt last array? it wont append

Comment: Not bad, but you may need to handle the last section outside the loop - it has no `''` at the end to force addition to the uber-list. I've added one way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one liner. It doesn't use itertools however.

```
   list = ['2', '', '9', '24', '1', '7', '12', '4', '', '18', '13', '34', '3', '10']
   formattedList = [x.split(" ") for x in " ".join(list).split("  ")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['2', '', '9', '24', '1', '7', '12', '4', '', '18', '13', '34', '3', '10']
temp=[]
b=[]
for i in a:
   if i =='':
      b.append(temp)
      temp=[]
   else:

      temp.append(i)
b.append(temp)
```